# Strive on vs Strive in

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

When strive is used without a direct object, should I use strive on, or strive in?

Example:

> I strive on getting success.
>
> VS
>
> I strive in getting success

Comment: Be careful not to confuse the word "strive" with the word "thrive". You can thrive in or thrive on something, but not strive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither. The idioms are "to strive for" a goal, "to strive towards" an objective, or "to strive to" accomplish something.

> I **strive for** excellence in all things.
>
> I **strive toward** excellence in all things.
>
> I **strive to** be excellent in all things.

You can also strive *against*, strive *through*, and various others.

I'm not sure *strive* can ever be used with a direct object, though I guess it depends on what a linguist considers an "object".  The example above with the infinitive "to be (excellent)" seems to qualify in [some definitions](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/strive).

Comment: How should I alter "I strive on getting success."

Comment: "I strive for success", "I strive towards success", "I strive to be successful".

Comment: What's the difference between for and towards.

Comment: The same as "I'm going **to** school" and "I'm going **towards** school".  "Towards" says that I'm not there yet, but that is my objective.

Comment: Should I use toward or towards

Comment: +1. **strive** is intransitive.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  Oxford seems to think so, but other dictionaries seemed mixed.  I'm going to let them fight it out.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  Wouldn't this usage of strive be intransitive, since strive is being followed by a prepositional phrase.

Comment: @user58712:  Correct, it is intransitive.